# memory effect in PDG

Tags: netlogo

I am trying simulate with netlogo a PDG and study the effect of memory in the cooperation. I want memory to be a coefficient m<1 that multiplicate the sum payoff at that time plus the cumulative historical payoff. I want to study the effect of the memory in the cooperation model and see the freqyency of cooperators in the world with and without the memory
thank you in advance

```
globals [payoffs]
patches-own [payments]
to setup
clear-all
; green: cooperate, red: defect
ask patches [
set payments []
set pcolor green
ifelse ( random-float 1.0 < cooperative-probability) [
  set pcolor green
] [
   set pcolor red
  ]
;; cooperate: 0, defect 1
set payoffs [[3 0] [4 1]]
]
 reset-ticks
end

to-report get-payment [my-color her-color]
  let my-action ifelse-value (my-color = green) [0] [1]
  let her-action ifelse-value (her-color = green) [0] [1]
  report item her-action (item my-action payoffs)
end

to go
  ask patches [
    play
  ]
  ask patches [
    update
 ]
  tick
end

; returns the first x elements in l, or fewer.
to-report first-x [x l]
  let result []
  if (length l = 0) [report []]
  repeat x [
    set result lput (first l) result
    set l butfirst l
    if (length l = 0) [
      report result
    ]
  ]
 report result
 end

; patches methods
to play
  let chosen-one one-of neighbors
  set payments fput (get-payment pcolor [pcolor] of chosen-one) payments
end

to-report gain
  report sum first-x history-length payments
end

to update
  let chosen-one one-of neighbors
  if ([gain] of chosen-one > gain) [
    set pcolor [pcolor] of chosen-one
  ]
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just posted my code ...

Comment: Can you explain a little further? What errors are you getting, what do you expect to have happen? It will probably help if you can break your problem into discrete coding issues, rather than presenting the model as a while. You may want to have a look at the [Asking Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the section on submitting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi, thank you for answering! I created a slider called memory length ju see that memory effects the cooperation to persist In a world. that slider goes from 1 to 50. but this way is too simple and I want now introduce memory as a coefficient of gain that multiplies just the cumulative historical payoffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to have a way of calculating a decaying cumulative variable value (payoff). The way to do this is to store the current value of the variable and, each tick, update that value with the total of the new payoff and the discounted value of the old cumulative payoff. This means that, for example, the payoff that is two ticks in the past has been discounted twice in the accumulation.

Here is a full model as an example. I have fixed the payoff to 5 each tick so you can see the effect of the memory.

```
globals [ memory ] ; how much to retain each tick
turtles-own [ payoff ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set memory 0.9
  create-turtles 1
  inspect one-of turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ let new-payoff 5
    set payoff new-payoff + memory * payoff
  ]
end
```

After the first tick, payoff is 5. After the second tick, payoff is 9.5 (=5+0.9*5). After the third tick, payoff is 13.55 (=5+0.9*9.5, which is also 5 + 0.9 * 5 + 0.9 * 0.9 * 5)

Comment: Awesome!!! thank you very much! How can I make memory a variable that goes form 0 to 1? in order to plot the density of cooperation as a function of memory to see how memory helps in keeping alive the cooperators in the world?

Comment: Any global variable can be set with a slider instead of having it as a declared global variable in the code. When you create a slider, you are in fact creating a global variable with that name.

Comment: hey Jen I tried to modify my code and put your suggested formula but when I run the world it gets me a routime error because the memory coefficient expect the payments to be a number but they are a list of numbers instead, as they should be.... can you please give an eye to my simulation and suggest me a way to fix the problem ?

Comment: You need to post a new question because this is a different problem. It sounds like you want to extract the number with the relevant payoff from your list.